# vb.net copied all files to another location with filter dates and show log

Tags: vb.net

I would to copy all files to another location, this program will filter -7 days, when it copied to another location, it will show the all file are copied in .log. I'm still in difficulties to get the log when ever i copied all the file to that location. Please see below:

```
Imports System

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click


        Dim DirectoryToCopy As String
        Dim NewCopy As String

        Dim d As Date = Date.Today
        d = d.AddDays(-7)


        DirectoryToCopy = "c:\test\hmm.gdb"
        NewCopy = "D:\Data\hmm.gdb"

        'NewCopy = "D:\Data\hmm.gdb" & d.AddDays(-7)

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\Data\update.log")


        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(DirectoryToCopy) = True Then

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(DirectoryToCopy, NewCopy, True)

            Directory.GetFiles(NewCopy, d)
            d = Directory.GetCreationTime(NewCopy)
            System.IO.File.Copy(DirectoryToCopy, NewCopy)
            ' System.IO.File.Copy(NewCopy, "D:\Data\update.log")


            'objWriter.WriteLine("file copy")
            'objWriter.Close()

            'MsgBox("File Copied")

        End If
 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Here .. I changed your code ..

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click


        Dim SourceFoDir As String= "C:\test"
        Dim TargetDir As String= "D:\Data"
        Dim NewCopy As String
        Dim oW As New System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim d As Date = Date.Today

        d = d.AddDays(-7)

        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(DirectoryToCopy) Then
        oW = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\Data\update.log", True)        

        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToCopy)

            file.copy(f & d.Date.ToString, TargetDir)
            oW.WriteLine(f & d.Date & " copied")

        Next

        oW.Close()
        End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi matzone, thank you so much for your help. But i can't see the update.log at my D:\Data. I'm only see the folder that i have copy from my previous command.  DirectoryToCopy = "c:\test\hmm.gdb"
        NewCopy = "D:\Data\hmm.gdb"

Comment: wow, thank you so much the helps. It is working.... i really appreciate the idea given

Comment: @LearnVB : You may vote this as the answer ... that would be fair enough .. :] :]